# Batch copy files from current directory using exclude

Tags: batch-file

I know i'm missing something really silly but would like some assistance.
I want to create a directory and then add contents into it. The actual location as of now are not the real thing.

C:\Location has some files such as text files or docx or anything.

C:\Location\word.docx and C:\Location\text.txt

I have done

```
MD "C:\Location\NewName" 
XCOPY C:\Location C:\Location\NewName /EXCLUDE C:\Location\NewName
```

I read about exclude and I added that in to avoid the cyclic problem but it still says can not perform cyclic copy. I would like to add the text files and docx files into the NewName folder. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot xcopy a folder when the destination is inside that folder.
That is what is generating the `cyclic copy` error.

You can xcopy to another location and then move the destination folder to where you need it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll rework on the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

if you are simply copying all files from a single folder, just use

```
copy location\* location\newname\
```

since only files will be copied, the fact that the destination folder is inside the same folder is irrelevant.